# When running a program as a Windows 7 service, where does the HOMEPATH variable map to?

Tags: windows-7, windows, environment-variables, services

I have a program that's being run as a Windows 7 service. In the program, the HOMEPATH environment variable is being used to set the location of a file. Normally, when the program is simply ran at a command line, HOMEPATH will be mapped to the logged in user's home directory. However, this isn't the case with a Windows service.

So when a program is ran as a service, and you use the HOMEPATH environment variable, where does that map to?

Comment: Most likely it is mapped to the c:\windows\system32 folder.

Comment: Couldn't you run an interactive CMD session as a service, to check? Have you tried just letting the program run and looking for the resulting file? Process Monitor can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services typically are run under one of three service accounts, `Local Service` `Local System` and `Network Service`. For all of which the HOMEPATH variable is **null**.

---

**To Investigate**

---

For your specific scenario you could have the service write an event log entry, and print what it stores in the HOMEPATH variable. In C# you could use:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("The HomePath for this service is '" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH") + "'", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

---

**Possible Solutions**

---

You can set what account a service uses (your user account for instance), in the services properties window or in the service install config. When I tested with my user account the event log entry displayed `The HomePath for this service is '\Users\Admin-PC'`.
 [image].
 [image]